# Using browser history with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Right now I have a system setup so that there are certain steps a person has to take to progress on a page. Im simply using show hide and to progress im using:

```
    function shownext(){
            $(this).next('div').fadeIn(500);
    }

    function showprev(){
            $(this).prev('div').fadeIn(500, backup);
    }
```

Is there a way I can get deep linking so that the person can go back to a previous step using the browser back button?

Comment: use `#anchors` to provide history path like `#stepone`,`#steptwo`...

Comment: There is a jQuery browser history plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919463/jquery-how-to-use-history-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) library makes it pretty easy to do this sort of thing using the HTML5 history API (with hash fallback for browsers lacking the API).

You could do something like:

```
function shownext(){
        $(this).next('div').fadeIn(500);
        // Push state with next page number.
}

function showprev(){
        $(this).prev('div').fadeIn(500, backup);
        // Push state with previous page number.
}

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
    var State = History.getState();
    goToPage(State.data.page);
}

function goToPage(page)
{
    // Go to page.
}
```

The documentation and demos for the library are very useful.